# Error running ROR commands in Textmate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

When I try to run some of the commands in the Ruby on Rails Textmate bundle, I get the following error:

> "Could not find activesupport-3.0.1 in
>   any of the sources Try running 'bundle
>   install'"

I have run 'bundle install' and it indicates activesupport is installed.

I have also tried running `gem install activesupport -v 3.0.1`

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

Are you by any chance using RVM in the mix too?

TextMate would be using the system Ruby - if this is the case you need to use the textmate wrapper for RVM [details here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate/)